# Squares of primes in the sequence 7 + 6k

Tags: prime-numbers

I was bored one day, and I stumbled across the fact that for the first few primes p (p >= 7 at least), have the fact that p^2 = 7 + 6k for some integer k. I couldn't prove it for all primes p >= 7 quickly (made a few stabs in the dark, but no luck), and I was wondering if this is a trivial fact and I'm missing something obvious? If not, are there any papers regarding representations of p^n, p prime, n an integer (preferably greater than 1)?

Comment: Looks better as $p^2=1+6n$ for some integer $n$. So we want to prove that $p^2$ has remainder $1$ on division by $6$, or equivalently remainder $1$ on division by $2$ and also on division by $3$. On division by $2$ is obvious. What about on division by $3$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every prime number greater than $3$ has the form $1+6k$ or $5+6k$ for some integer $k$.  The reason is that $6k$, $2+6k$, and $4+6k$ are even, and $6k$, $3+6k$ are divisible by $3$.  Every number has to be of the form $j+6k$ for some $j\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$, so this covers all cases.

So when you square a prime greater than $3$, you get $(1+6k)^2=1+6(2k+6k^2)$, or $(5+6k)^2=1+6(4+10k+6k^2)$.  In either case, this shows that the square of a prime number greater than $3$ has the form $1+6j$ for some integer $j$.  Notice that $1+6j=7+6(j-1)$, so this implies the result you observed.

Comment: Could have avoided that tediousness if $5 (6)$ was interpreted as $-1 (6)$

Comment: @KannappanSampath: Good point.  I was naïvely keeping things in the usual remainder after division by $6$ form, so I used $5$ without thinking much of economy or elegance.

Comment: Ah, thanks, missed the obvious! Also answers my question about p^k.

Comment: @Mike: You're welcome.  In case you aren't aware, you may be interested in a framework for thinking about such problems given by [modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).  Here we are working in the ring of congruence classes modulo $6$, with the sample multiplication facts $\overline1^2= \overline1$ and $\overline5^2=\overline 1$.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Thanks for the tip, I have seen some modular arithmetic before. My original question has led me to another which is this: What is the distribution of p^k mod n, and are there interesting n for which this distribution has interesting properties? (Much too vague for another math.SE at the moment, and I'm trying to do more homework this time).

Answer (score 1):

**HINT** $\: $ Generally $\rm\:n\:$ coprime to $\rm\: 6\ \Rightarrow\ n^2 \equiv\: 1\pmod{24}\ $ since

$\rm\qquad 3\nmid n\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ mod\ 3\!:\ \ n\ \equiv\ \pm 1\ \Rightarrow\ n^2\ \equiv\ 1 $

$\rm\qquad 2\nmid n\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ mod\ 8\!: \ \ n\ \equiv \pm1,\:\pm3\ \Rightarrow\ n^2\ \equiv 1$

Your example is a special case, since primes $> 3$ are coprime to $2$ and $3$ so coprime to $6$.