# If $p$ is a prime then $p^2+26$ is not a prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures

I have tested for all primes less than  $40,000$ and it seems that, if $p$ is a prime then $p^2+26$ is not. I would like to see a proof or a counter-example.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150952/proving-all-primes-are-1-or-1-modulo-6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $x$ is not divisible by $3$, then $x^2 \equiv 1\mod3$. So for the primes we have

$$p^2+26\equiv 0\mod3$$

**Edit.**

As [user236182](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/236182/user236182) noted, we should separately treat the case of $p = 3$, because in this case my reasons are not valid. For this prime we have $p^2+26 = 35$, which is not prime.

Comment: Except when $p=3$. Then $35=5\cdot 7$ is still not prime.

Comment: And also $p^2+26>3$.

Answer (score 1):

For primes $p > 3$, 3 divides the quantity  $p^2 - 1$ (proof provided [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/855/for-any-prime-p-3-why-is-p2-1-always-divisible-by-24)), so for some integer $n$, $$3n = p^2 - 1$$ and $$p^2 + 26 = (p^2 - 1) + 27 = 3n + 27 = 3(n+9)$$
Since 3 does not divide any primes greater than 3, and by observation $p^2 + 26$ is not prime for $p \le 3$, we can conclude that $p^2 + 26$ is composite.